# Laravel empty object in edit / show function

Tags: php, laravel

this is my first post on stackoverflow. I've created my first project with Laravel a few months ago, it contains some models, controllers, observers etc, but I have stucked in the last one, which was created in the same way as previous ones (I guess...), I can't find what I've missed this time. Creating records work fine, but editing or showing unfortunately no: function edit(ExpenseCourse $expenseCourse) should show array with 1 record indexed in URL http://.......expensecourses/1/edit but it shows empty array.
Table expense_courses is not empty, it contains one previously created record with id = 1
The same situation is with the show method.

Here is my ExpenseCourseController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\ExpenseCourse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Auth;

class ExpenseCourseController extends Controller
{
    
    public function edit(ExpenseCourse $expenseCourse)
    {

        dd($expenseCourse);
        $depts = DB::table('depts')
            ->where('company_id','=',1)
            ->orderby('dept_shortname')
            ->get();

        return view('expensecourses.edit',compact('expenseCourse'), [
            'depts' => $depts,
        ]);
    }
    
}
```

Here is my ExpenseCourse.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ExpenseCourse extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'dept_id', 'name', 'company_name', 'year', 'hours_count', 'estimated_participants_number', 'estimated_price', 'real_price', 'status_id', 'planned' 
    ];
}
```

Here is my migration 2021_12_17_140931_create_expense_courses_table.php file.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateExpenseCoursesTable extends Migration
{
   
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('expense_courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('dept_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('company_name');
            $table->year('year');
            $table->integer('hours_count');
            $table->integer('estimated_participants_number');
            $table->integer('estimated_price');
            $table->integer('real_price')->nullable();
            $table->integer('status_id')->default(1);
            $table->boolean('planned')->default(1);
            $table->integer('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->integer('updated_by')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

   
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('expense_courses');
    }
}
```

Here is my route web.php file

```
   <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use App\Http\Controllers\ParticipantController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\CoursesTypesController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\TrainerController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\CourseController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\ExpenseCourseController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\DeptController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\PositionsTypesController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\PrintTemplatesController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\ReportsController;
    
    
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome2');
    });
    
    
    
    Auth::routes();
    
    
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    Route::resource('participants', ParticipantController::class)->middleware('auth');
    Route::resource('coursestypes', CoursesTypesController::class)->middleware('auth');
    Route::resource('trainers', TrainerController::class)->middleware('auth');
    Route::resource('courses', CourseController::class)->middleware('auth');
    Route::resource('expensecourses', ExpenseCourseController::class)->middleware('auth');
    Route::resource('companies', CompanyController::class)->middleware('auth');
    Route::resource('depts', DeptController::class)->middleware('auth');
    Route::resource('positionstypes', PositionsTypesController::class)->middleware('auth');
    
    
    Route::get('participants/fill/{course_id}', [ParticipantController::class, 'fill'])->name('participants/fill')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('participants/create/{course_id}', [ParticipantController::class, 'create'])->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('participants/edit/{participant_id}/{course_id}', [ParticipantController::class, 'edit'])->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('search/results', [CourseController::class, 'results'])->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('search/query', [CourseController::class, 'search'])->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('companies/getdepts/{company_id}', [CompanyController::class, 'getdepts'])->name('companies/getdepts')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('prints/print/{participant_id}', [PrintTemplatesController::class, 'print'])->name('prints/print')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('reports/quantity', [ReportsController::class, 'quantity_report'])->middleware('auth'); // raport ilościowy
    Route::get('reports/annual', [ReportsController::class, 'annual_report'])->middleware('auth'); // raport roczny
    
    
   URL::forceScheme('https');
```

I would be gratefull if you could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because variable and constants are case sensitive in php and in your case name of `Route::resource` does not match parameter name in the method of the controller class. You can change either your route name or your parameters in `edit` and `show` method.

#### 1. Change route name:

Use camelcase in route name, change `expensecourses` to `expenseCourses`

```
Route::resource('expenseCourses', ExpenseCourseController::class)->middleware('auth');
```

**OR**

#### 2. Change parameter name

```php
public function edit(ExpenseCourse $expensecourse){}

public function show(ExpenseCourse $expensecourse){}
```